# Word JS API: insert date into content control

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, office-addins

How can I insert a date in the word content control using Office JS API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the date (formatted as you like) to a string var and then pass the var as the first parameter to the [ContentControl.insertText](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/word/word.contentcontrol?view=word-js-preview#insertText_text__insertLocation_) method.

Comment: The date content control cannot be used? I can only use a text content control

Comment: You can only use a Rich Text control.